# Access Chromebook Device info in G Suite Using Google App Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, device, google-workspace

We manage our Chromebook Inventory using Google Sheets in addition to G Suite Admin. Im at a point now that I need to read/write to G Suite Devices using script. I'm Fairly new to script but I can follow along well. I can't find any info relative to this to get me started. 
I use Gopher Addon to export and import to G Suite which is great but I need that functionality from script.